# How to select nodes without taxonomy terms from a vocabulary in views?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

Is it possible to select all nodes that have no taxonomy terms from a vocabulary in views?

I tried the "is empty" option in the filter section, but it does not work.

I need to do that in views because I have to use VBO on the results of the query.

Answer (score 0):

yes i think so.. for me it works when i select 'has taxonomy term' and next option 'is empty'

Comment: in the filter criteria you add filter "has taxonomy term", then you chose the vocabulary and the "is empty"?
and it works? It does not work for me.